# Computing the JWT signature for Google OAuth Service Account using erlang?

Tags: erlang, google-oauth, jwt, sha256, rsa-sha256

I have created google service account and have JSON file containing `private_key`, `client_email` etc.

[JWT should be created](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatingjwt) to [get access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#makingrequest).

I have followed following step

Header computation:

```
Header = jsx:encode(#{<<"alg">> => <<"RS256">>,<<"typ">> => <<"JWT">>}).
Base64Header = base64:encode(Header).
```

Claims computation:

```
Claims = jsx:encode(#{
  <<"iss">> => <<"google-123@some-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com">>,
  <<"scope">> => <<"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform">>,
  <<"aud">> => <<"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token">>,
  <<"exp">> => 1471629262,
  <<"iat">> => 1471627282
}).
Base64Claims = base64:encode(Claims).


Input = {Base64Header}.{Base64Claim}
```

And,
How we can sign the UTF-8 representation of the `Input` using SHA256withRSA (also known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function) with the `private_key` to compute JWT Signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libraries already built to do this. One (which I am using) is [Erlang JOSE](https://github.com/potatosalad/erlang-jose).

```
%% In OTP 17 or later
Signed = jose_jwt:sign(RSAPrivate, #{ <<"alg">> => <<"RS256">> }, Payload),
{_JWS, Token} = jose_jws:compact(Signed).
```

Comment: the question asked how to do it, not to link a library. I am interested myself, and jose_jwt code is quite hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://github.com/kivra/oauth2_client
As of version 1.4.0 it supports authorization with a Service Account credentials JSON file, there is a pull request I created with the example https://github.com/kivra/oauth2_client/pull/26.